# How to Change btn-color according to SQL database

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, web-deployment

```
<td><span class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" onclick="reviewLiveScholarship('<?php echo $ship->id;?>')">Review</span></td>
```

I need to change the button color according to the data from database, where required documents are there ( either 1 or 0).

This button directs into the result page where the documents where shown.

Code is written in CodeIgniter.

Comment: Change color for condition-based EX: 0 or 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
$color = "background-color: #5cb85c;";
      }
      echo "<button class='ServiceOff btn glyphicon glyphicon-globe' name='on_off' value='".$token_id."' style='".$color." color: #fff;''></button>";
   } // <-- *** YOU NEED TO ADD THIS ***
} else {
  echo "Error";
}
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but a better answer would take the OP's code and modify it to work, rather than just giving a random example (presumably a snippet from your own code, most of which  (e.g. the else clause and brackets isn't even relevant).